# A specific marginal effect for logistic regression

Tags: self-study, logistic, econometrics, marginal-effect

For the logit estimate of the slope parameter,I would like to obtain the marginal effect of the regressor ndisease evaluated at $\Lambda (x'\beta)=\bar{y}$.

I obtain the logic estimation as follows:

[image]

How can I calculate this marginal effect by using Stata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the equation

$$\Lambda (\alpha + \beta \cdot x) = \bar{y}$$

You have the logit coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and you can calculate $\bar y = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N y_i $. Now you can solve that to get $x$. Then you can calculate [the marginal effect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/415949/7071) at that value of $x$ by taking the derivative.

Here's an example:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 automobile data)

. logit foreign mpg, nolog

Logistic regression                                     Number of obs =     74
                                                        LR chi2(1)    =  11.49
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0007
Log likelihood = -39.28864                              Pseudo R2     = 0.1276

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |   .1597621   .0525876     3.04   0.002     .0566922     .262832
       _cons |  -4.378866   1.211295    -3.62   0.000    -6.752961   -2.004771
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. sum foreign

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |         74    .2972973    .4601885          0          1

. margins // equivalent to above

Predictive margins                                          Number of obs = 74
Model VCE: OIM

Expression: Pr(foreign), predict()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   .2972973   .0487662     6.10   0.000     .2017172    .3928773
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. display "mpg at y-bar = " (logit(.2972973) -  _b[_cons])/_b[mpg]
mpg at y-bar = 22.024397

. margins, dydx(mpg) at(mpg = 22.024397)

Conditional marginal effects                                Number of obs = 74
Model VCE: OIM

Expression: Pr(foreign), predict()
dy/dx wrt:  mpg
At: mpg = 22.0244

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |   .0333762   .0113403     2.94   0.003     .0111495    .0556028
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This means that the marginal effect of a *small* increase in miles per gallon is associated with a ~3.3% increase in the probability of foreign origin. This is an approximation, but not so bad compared to an exact change of $.3317149-.2972973 = .0344176$ from a one unit increase:

```
. margins, at(mpg = (22.024397 23.024397))

Adjusted predictions                                        Number of obs = 74
Model VCE: OIM

Expression: Pr(foreign), predict()
1._at: mpg = 22.0244
2._at: mpg = 23.0244

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         _at |
          1  |   .2972973   .0580565     5.12   0.000     .1835087    .4110859
          2  |   .3317149   .0618281     5.37   0.000      .210534    .4528958
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```